# Can't prevent the deletion of a row

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework-2.3

I am trying to prevent the deletion of a row of my Lab table when there's still rows refering it.

Here is the script of the table Lab:

```
CREATE TABLE Lab (
    id      INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    acronym VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    name    VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    email   VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    logoId  VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Here is the script of one table referring to it:

```
CREATE TABLE AppUser (
    id        INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    firstName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    lastName  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    email     VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    lab       INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
        REFERENCES Lab(id)
            ON DELETE  RESTRICT,
    hashedPass VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    role      INT NOT NULL,
    rememberMeToken VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I don't know why but it seems that the ON DELETE RESTRICT doesn't prevent my Scala/Playframework from deleting any of my Lab.

Here is the Scala function that deletes:

```
def destroy(lab: Lab):Boolean = DB.withConnection {implicit c =>
    try {
      SQL("DELETE FROM Lab WHERE id = {id}")
        .on("id" -> lab.id)
        .executeUpdate()
      true
    } catch {
      case e: SQLException
        if e.getMessage.contains("update or delete on table \"lab\" violates foreign key constraint \"conference_organizedby_fkey\" on table \"conference\"") |
           e.getMessage.contains("update or delete on table \"lab\" violates foreign key constraint \"appuser_lab_fkey\" on table \"appuser\"")
        => Logger.warn(e.getMessage); false
    }
  }
```

I use anorm as data access layer.

Do you think I've done it wrong, or have any suggestions to make it work?

Else I maybe should just test into my controller when calling the destroy(lab), but it seems not the better way to me.

Thanks

Comment: You have shown the code of `Lab` and `AppUser`, while you are deleting `Conference.`

Comment: Thanks @johny, just messed up when creating the post.

Comment: Anorm is based on plain JDBC. JDBC can't overcome DB constraints. I suggest you print the parameters with which the statement is executed, and try to execute it manually.

Comment: For this to work, InnoDB has to be the storage engine for the table.  Is it?

Comment: InnoDB is the storage engine for every table on my database, I really can't understand why these constraint don't works... @Michael-sqlbot

Comment: And even when using the statement on the workbench, this delete the lab even when there is an appuser. @cchantep

Comment: Aha. In `AppUser`, you have `lab bigint NOT NULL` but in `lab` you have `id INT UNSIGNED`.  Data types must match exactly on constraints.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I changed my constraint so that it matches types like you said but it still doesn't work, I can delete a lab who has users whith a simple: `DELETE FROM Lab WHERE id = 1` into mysql workbench